# "One of the tools I use is/are magnet/magnets"

Tags: modal-verbs, singular-vs-plural

I'm trying to wrap my head around whether any of the following are correct (apart from #3):

1) One of the tools I use **is magnets**.

2) One of the tools I use **are magnets**.

3) One of the tools I use **is the magnet**.

For #1, I'm not sure if it's correct or not. The assumption I'm making here is that "magnets" could be a collective, but I could be wrong.

For #2, since "one" is the subject, I'm fairly certain it's wrong.

For #3, I'm sure it's correct, but it doesn't have the same effect of plurality that I want to convey.

Any ideas or advice? Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: One=is. Two=are. Magnets cannot be collective. One magnet, two magnets.

Comment: You could rephrase the end of the sentence to make it singular while still referring to multiple magnets: "a pair of magnets," or "a set of magnets."

Answer (score 1):

**One of the tools I use is the magnet**

This sentence is most correct because *one* *is* and *the magnet* are all singular.

Native English speakers often will say it like "One of the tools I use are magnets," because sentences like this are confusing.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I would discourage **most correct**. It's either correct or incorrect although it might be the most suitable, the most appropriate, the best choice or simply preferable.